# Remove white line from Table with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Can someone help me remove the white line just below my top banner.
In Firefox you can't see the line, but it's visible in IE and Chrome.

You can see it here http://www.direkte-el.dk/default.aspx

Would prefer a JQuery solution, since it's the only way I can change the layout.

Sorry the page is in Danish, but you should still be able to understand my problem.

Comment: Hi Im stil looking for a solution for IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$('#tblBanner').remove();
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like it only removed it in Chrome, but its still visible in Internet Explorer.

The source for my js http://www.direkte-el.dk/images/editor/bundtekst.js

Comment: Any suggesting for fixing it in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Needed to remove the clostest tr for it to work in IE, but thx for helping me.

 $('#tblBanner').closest('tr').remove();